# Php - Zend 2 lock cache file after read

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework2, locking

I am using zend 2 cache and I need modify a cache file and make sure no other process read the file while I am doing that.Is there a way to lock the cache file after read it then write and unlock ?
I am more interested if Zend 2 cache already allow you to do that and if not what others way are in php to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [zf2 docs - filesystem cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#the-filesystem-adapter) there is a boolean config param `file_locking` which does `Lock files on writing`.

Comment: I want to lock them after reading and be able to unlock them after writing in them.

Comment: Will this happen in a single request - read and write? Or first request read + lock, next request write + unlock?